# Example code for java.util.zip.Deflater that uses batch modes for both input and output

Tags: java, zlib

The example code in the javadoc for [java.util.zip.Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) is too optimistic, and assumes that you have a byte array containing all input, and a byte array that is large enough for the output. >:(

Is there an example somewhere that calls both `needsInput()` to add input in batches, and `finished()` to get output in batches? I can't seem to find one, and the docs are a little hazy about what is the right order of operations.

Example:

- I have a `ByteBuffer` that is a 100MB memory-mapped file
- I'm writing the output to a stream
- I have a these byte arrays of length 1024 for batches of input and output:

  ```
  byte[] inbatch = new byte[1024];
  byte[] outbatch = new byte[1024];
  ```

It seems like something like this might work, but I'm not sure, and I suspect there may be some subtle edge cases...

```
 Deflater deflater = ...;
 byte[] inbatch = new byte[1024];
 byte[] outbatch = new byte[1024];

 boolean inputDone = false;
 while (true)
 {
     if (!inputDone && deflater.needsInput())
     {
        int n = get_more_input(..., inbatch);
        if (n == 0)
           inputDone = true;
        else
           deflater.setInput(inbatch, 0, n);
     }

     if (deflater.finished()
     {
        if (inputDone)
           break;
     }
     else
     {
        int n = deflater.deflate(outbatch);
        handle_output(outbatch, n);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you looked at DeflaterInputStream (and Output) ? They both use a Deflater with randomly sized inputs of datas.

Comment: To the Closer-istas: OK guys, how can I improve the question? This is definitely about programming and I'm trying to be as clear as possible.